# Find max length of each column in a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.6 along with the xlwt and pyodbc modules to create excel reports from a view on an MS SQL Sever (2008).  In order to programatically set the correct width of each field in excel, I would like to retrieve the maximum length of the values in each column.

For example

```
foo=[[1, 'This is a test',12039],[12, 'test',1235]]
```

Would result in `[2,14,5]`

I'm sure there is an easy solution that I'm just overlooking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[max(len(str(x)) for x in line) for line in zip(*foo)]
```

Comment: Yup. For user589983, basically zip(*foo) transposes the list (e.g., `[(1,12), ('This ... ]`) then iterates through the lines (1,12), then iterates through the items in each line (x) finding the length of each represented as a string, and returns the maximum of these length for each line.

Comment: Not sure why, but this code generated a list of max values for me, so I applied an additional [link]max[/link] statement to pull the highest value from the generated list.

Comment: @artifex_knowledge This code produces a list of the lengths of the longest value in each column.  See the example given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the input lists are very long, itertools.izip() might be a better choice than zip() since it will return an iterator instead of a long list, so you can save some memory space.